# GWT: Why doesn't "setAnimationEnabled(true);" respect DialogBox size?

Tags: java, gwt, animation

I am extending GWT [DialogBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/index.html) and my constructor looks like:

```
public MyBox() {
  setGlassEnabled(true);
  setAnimationEnabled(true);
  setWidth("400px");
  VerticalPanel contents = new VerticalPanel();
  contents.setWidth("400px");
  // init widgets
}
```

When I comment out second line everything works well. With animation enabled is the size of my dialog "broken". When I inspect HTML site the element has correctly 400px, but it just doesn't fully animate :/

I have few such widgets (animated boxes) and some (smaller ones) works well. What might be the problem? Thanks

**EDIT:**

[image]

Here is weird thing. The table element has 432px, but my DialogBox has 400px set everywhere and no padding set. I tried to force padding 0 with css and still no result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the width before setting animationEnabled? Are you using an XML layout? MAybe try setting the width in there instead of in the class? I suspect the animation actually tweaks the width property and those two are conflicting.

Comment: I tried setting it before and it didn't help. I inspected element at runtime (with chrome inspector) at size of div is correct. It's definitelly something to do with animations, but no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at an example of something I did that does the same, and I changed the size of the HTMLPanel that is contained inside the dialog box, not the size of the dialog box itself. And this works with animationEnabled.

Comment: DialogBox has inside itself VerticalPanel and both are same width, I added more code. I also added screenshot from Chrome inspector.